# Karabiner Elements: Why is a series (or sequence/batch) of keys called in {…"to": …} only executed every second time?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu, karabiner, macos

I used the original Karabiner app 10.22 and could very precisely restrict any actions via Apple's Accessibility Inspector to work for specific dialogue windows.

This is no longer possible with Karabiner Elements.

So in order to (in Safari) click the context menu's item "Element Information" (which I use very often) I tried this code in "Complex Modifications":

```
 "to": [ { "pointing_button": "button2" },
         { "key_code": "e" },
         { "key_code": "return_or_enter"}  ]
```

Which *did* work, but alternately only opened/showed the context menu *or* actually executed "Element Information".

By experimenting, I found a workaround that mostly works for me:

```
"parameters": { "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 50 }, 
"to":       [ { "pointing_button": "button2" } ],
"to_if_held_down":
            [ { "key_code": "e" },
              { "key_code": "return_or_enter"} ]
```

My questions:

Why are not *all* "commands" in the first code example executed in due order (or: only alternately) and (more interestingly:) how can you ensure that *each* "command" is executed *every* time?

Comment: Maybe ask at the dedicated Karabiner forum? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/osx-karabiner

Answer (score 3):

I think your workaround perfectly demonstrates the reason: you are selecting "Element information" via the GUI, and the context menu may take a few milliseconds to be brought up. This isn't an issue with Karabiner specifically — if the <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd> keycodes are sent instantaneously after right-clicking, the context menu may not be in focus yet, and they won't be directed appropriately.

In short, if you're making a GUI macro, you may need to wait for the GUI to respond.

As I see it, there are three possible solutions:

- simply add a brief delay, as you've done,
- use an alternate tool (e.g. Keyboard Maestro) which allows you to pause until a certain condition is filled, or
- use an alternate method of activating the desired outcome, i.e. something which doesn't rely on the graphical user interface at the user level, such as AppleScript (though I don't know if such an option exists for this specific goal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that addresses the first part (why) of my question; the second part (how2) still is what is most interesting in order to get a fail-safe method (not depending on cpu, RAM etc.). I cured the "why" with my workaround, but this will not work on every computer, maybe not even on my own if too many apps are working simultaneously. I vote your answer up one, so if nobody finds a how2-answer, you'll get the bounty ... :-)

Comment: [ADDED TOO LATE:] … if s.o. else "agrees" … :-)

Comment: @clemsamlang I've added my reply to my answer, since it didn't fit nicely in a comment. :)

Comment: – I appreciate this … you don't happen to have an idea, how K-E can be made to actually WAIT for a GUI event?

Comment: @clemsamlang I’m not very familiar with the scripting side of KE. I’d have to do more research.

Comment: I suggest that someone reading this thread "up" your/Timothy*s answer to +2: that way it will get half the "bounty". As the important (2nd) part of my question is not answered, I would not want  this thread to look like there was a final answer …